# command to transpose two adjacent windows when I have more than two windows?

Tags: window

My idea was kind of this (but I'm open for other suggestions):

I need

1. a functions to get names of windows (not frames)
2. a way to read the current window configuration.
   e.g. `(vertically-split a (horizontally-split b c))`
3. a functions to transpose 2 windows / modify window configuration.
   e.g. `(vertically-split a (horizontally-split b c))` -> `(vertically-split (horizontally-split b c) a)` -> `(vertically-split (horizontally-split c b) a)`

Comment: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TransposeWindows has some examples

Comment: You can accept your own answer (or any other answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M-x package-install buffer-move

```
'buf-move-left
'buf-move-right
'buf-move-up
'buf-move-down
```

were exactly what i'm looking for.
thanks @npostavs for pointing me to https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TransposeWindows

Answer (score 4):

The `ace-swap-window` command in the [ace-window package](https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window) does exactly this. If you install that package, the command `C-u M-x ace-window` will swap the contents of the current window with the one you select. If you do that a lot you'll want to bind it to something more convenient.

I don't understand what your point #3 has to do with points 1 and 2. I use the following function to toggle back and forth between a 2-window horizontal configuration and a 2-window vertical configuration.

```
(defun toggle-window-split ()
  (interactive)
  (if (= (count-windows) 2)
      (let* ((this-win-buffer (window-buffer))
             (next-win-buffer (window-buffer (next-window)))
             (this-win-edges (window-edges (selected-window)))
             (next-win-edges (window-edges (next-window)))
             (this-win-2nd (not (and (<= (car this-win-edges)
                                         (car next-win-edges))
                                     (<= (cadr this-win-edges)
                                         (cadr next-win-edges)))))
             (splitter
              (if (= (car this-win-edges)
                     (car (window-edges (next-window))))
                  'split-window-horizontally
                'split-window-vertically)))
        (delete-other-windows)
        (let ((first-win (selected-window)))
          (funcall splitter)
          (if this-win-2nd (other-window 1))
          (set-window-buffer (selected-window) this-win-buffer)
          (set-window-buffer (next-window) next-win-buffer)
          (select-window first-win)
          (if this-win-2nd (other-window 1))))))
```

Comment: Interesting! but not what i was loking for. but it will be usefull some other time ;) or can you switch to the 'next' (without choosing it) even with more than 2 windows?

Comment: Which window is next if you have more than two? If you can explain what you want, it can be done. With ace-window selecting a window is done with a single keypress, so it's very quick & flexible

Answer (score 0):

Here, check this out.

```el
(defun window-children (window)
  "Return the children of WINDOW."
  (let ((child (window-child window))
        children)
    (while child
      (push child children)
      (setq child (window-next-sibling child)))
    (nreverse children)))

(defun window-transpose-siblings (&optional n k)
  "Transpose the K-th parent with its N-th sibling.

K defaults to 0 and N to 1, i.e. transpose the `selected-window'
with its right (or below) sibling.

Interactively, K is 0 and N the prefix-arg.  Unless this argument
is negative, in which case K is minus the prefix-arg and N equals
1.  The command remembers the last set value of K across
different invocations."
  (interactive
   (let ((n (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg))
         (k (get this-command 'k)))
     (when (<= n 0)
       (setq k (- n) n 1)
       (put this-command 'k k))
     (list n k)))
  (unless n (setq n 1))
  (unless k (setq k 0))
  (let* ((w0 (selected-window)))
    ;; Go up K window nodes.
    (dotimes (_ k)
      (setq w0 (window-parent w0)))
    ;; Figure out the window to transpose with and do it.
    (let* ((siblings (window-children (window-parent w0)))
           (w1 (nth (mod (+ n (cl-position w0 siblings))
                         (length siblings))
                    siblings))
           (s0 (window-state-get w0))
           (s1 (window-state-get w1)))
      (unless (eq w0 w1)
        (window-state-put s1 w0)
        (window-state-put s0 w1))
      nil)))
```